# Undesireable withe space between paragraphs after a landscape page

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, line-spacing, landscape, pdflscape

writing a document I founded that after a `landscape` page, `LaTeX` was leaving a big withe space between paragraphs after a `subsection` heading, especially when the paragraph had less than 3 lines. When the first paragraph after the section had more than 3 lines, there was no problem. Any hint why it is happening?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\linespread{1.3}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\blindtext\par
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
A Figure
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}
\blindtext\par
\blindtext
\blindtext\par
\subsection{A long long long long longlong long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long Title}
A sentence with less than 3 lines.\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

More than 3 lines

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Probably an `\afterpage` feature.

It can be avoided by putting `\clearpage` before the section heading (which leaves the heading in the same place but flushes out the afterpage before the page heading code kicks in.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\linespread{1.3}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\blindtext\par
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
A Figure
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}%
}%

\blindtext\par
\blindtext
\blindtext\par
\clearpage
\subsection{A long long long long longlong long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long Title}
A sentence with less than 3 lines.\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

note this warns

```
Package mathdesign/mdbch Warning: Package 'amsfonts' shouldn't be used
in conjonction with package mdbch, on input line 24.
```

I would not use `afterpage` or `landscape` her but rather a rotated float

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\linespread{1.3}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\blindtext\par

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[htb]
\centering
A Figure
\end{sidewaysfigure}


\blindtext\par
\blindtext
\blindtext\par
\clearpage % if you want it
\subsection{A long long long long longlong long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long Title}
A sentence with less than 3 lines.\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works partially, I liked. But if I need to put some text before the figure, the document doesn't  look good